# Why is the Analyze menu disabled in QtCreator

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator

I'm trying to analyse (valgrind) a program on linux using QtCreator. But the menu in qt creator is disabled.

I have OpenSuse 13.1. linux on 64bit. This is what i tried so far:

- I've checked the plugins dialogue and the Valgrind plugin is greyed out, but selected.
- I've checked the installation directory and the plugin is there.
- Valgrind is installed (valgrind --version -> valgrind-3.8.1)
- valgrind works (valgrind --tool=callgrind ./myprog)
- I tried the stock version of QtCreator (2.8.1) and a newer installation in ~/bin/Qt.. (3.4.0)
- I tried it with a qmake and a cmake project.
- I tried to re-enable the QtQuick plugins. This made the menu work and the Analyse icon on the left appeared, but still no valgrind support.

Can anybody help?

Comment: In Qt Creator 3.4.0, if you go to `Tools -> Options... -> Analyzer`, is the path to the `valgrind` executable set?

Comment: There is no Analyzer Icon in the Options nor did I find it as a tab in any of the icons.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable the Devices->RemoteLinux plugin as well.